# Poly-count for final render?

Tags: polycount

So, the poly-count feature in the bottom right-hand corner reflects viewport data.

If I want to see the count post-modifiers (the final render value) how would I do that? I have a rather large scene with many modifiers hidden/lessened to avoid lagging and crashes and want to see how large my project *really* is before I hit render.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender, sadly, does not currently calculate the poly-count the final render quality of a mesh object. I tried going into the rendered viewport. It shows the final surface quality of the objects, but the count does not change to the amount of vertices in the scene. I hope that Blender has that feature in later editions.

Comment: If this is the answer, mind blown. Such a critical piece of information to leave out of this software. Thank you.